# How to copy specific part of row VBA Excel to another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I solved it on my own. I added a for loop. Here is my working code. Thanks to everyone else for trying to help.

```
Sub runMatch()

Dim critRemID, listRemID, critRemIDstart, listRemIDstart As Range

Set critRemID = Worksheets("Enterprise - score").Cells(2, 1)
Set listRemID = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
Set critRemIDstart = Worksheets("Enterprise - score").Cells(2, 30)
Set listRemIDstart = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)

Dim i, j, index As Integer
i = 0
j = 0

    Do While critRemID.Offset(i, 0) <> ""
    If critRemID.Offset(i, 0) = listRemID.Offset(j, 0) Then
    For index = 0 To 84
    critRemIDstart.Offset(i, index) = listRemIDstart.Offset(j, index).Value
    Next index
    i = i + 1
    j = 0
    index = 0
    Else
    If listRemID.Offset(j, 0) = "" Then
    j = 0
    i = i + 1
    Else
    j = j + 1
    End If
    End If

    Loop


End Sub
```

> I have two sheets, they each have a the same IDs on each sheet but
>   different sets of data.
>
> I want to scan through the rows of data and if there is a match, copy
>   the entire row from a certain column to another certain column to the
>   end of one of the sheets.
>
> Sheet 1 is the sheet I want to copy info into, on the end I've created
>   the same headers for the data I want to bring over from sheet 2.
>
> the code below is what I have, I set a range up for the IDs and one
>   for where I want the copied cells to start
>
> ```
> Dim critRemID, listRemID, critRemIDstart, listRemIDstart As Range
>
> Set critRemID = Worksheets("Enterprise - score").Cells(2, 1)
> Set listRemID = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
> Set critRemIDstart = Worksheets("Enterprise - score").Cells(2, 30)
> Set listRemIDstart = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 90)
>
> Dim i, j As Integer
> i = 0
> j = 0
>
>
> Do While critRemID.Offset(i, 0) <> ""
> If critRemID.Offset(i, 0) = listRemID.Offset(j, 0) Then
> critRemIDstart.Row(i) = listRemIDstart.Row(j).Value
> i = i + 1
> j = 0
> Else
> j = j + 1
> End If
>
> Loop
> ```
>
> I keep getting this error
>
> > Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
>
> I tried going a different route but kept getting confused as shown
>   below. I was trying to have it copy each cell one by one and once it
>   reached an empty cell, it would move onto the next ID on the main
>   sheet and start over but this does nothing, I think it keeps
>   increasing both IDs on the sheet and never finds a match.
>
> ```
> If critRemID.Offset(i, 0) = listRemID.Offset(j, 0) Then
> critRemIDstart.Offset(i, k) = listRemIDstart.Offset(j, l).Value
> k = k + 1
> l = l + 1
> Else
> If listRemIDstart.Offset(j, l) = "" Then
>     j = j + 1
>     l = 0
>     i = i + 1
>     k = 0
> Else
> j = j + 1
> i = i + 1
> l = 0
> k = 0
> End If
> End if
> ```
>
> any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: look up the meaning of the word `throw` ... you used it incorrectly in the second sentence

Comment: `Range.Row` return the row number of the range.

Answer (score 1):

`Range.Find` method could find the key easily.

```
Dim critRem, listRem As Worksheet
Set critRem = Worksheets("Enterprise - score")
Set listRem = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim critRemID, listRemID, cell, matchedCell As Range

With critRem
    Set critRemID = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With
With listRem
    Set listRemID = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In critRemID
    Set matchedCell = listRemID.Find(cell.Value)
    If matchedCell Is Nothing Then 'ID is not found
        'Do nothing
    Else 'ID is found, matchedCell is pointed to column A now
        cell.Offset(0, 29).Resize(1, 10) = matchedCell.Offset(0, 89).Resize(1, 10)
        'offset(0,29) means offsetting right 29 columns
        'resize(0,10) means resizing the range with 1 row and 10 columns width
        'feel free to change the number for your data
    End If
Next cell
```

Note: If you are confused about `offset().resize()`, there is another approach. `cell.Row` gives you the row that the data should be written into, and `matchedCell.Row` gives you the row that the ID matched. So you can access certain cell by something like `listRem.Range("D" & matchedCell.Row)`

Answer (score 1):

If as you say both sheets have the same IDs, then why not use a Vlookup function to bring the data into Sheet1, then simply copy the results and paste as values so you get rid of the formula on them cells?

Something like a loop running:

```
For i = 1 to LastRow
Sheet1.cells(i, YourColumnNumber).value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], Sheet2!R1:R1048576, 3, False)"
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Tried to do it using the loop.

    Sub Anser()

        Dim critRemID           As Range
        Dim listRemID           As Range
        Dim critRemIDstart      As Range
        Dim listRemIDstart      As Range

'::::Change Sheet names and column numbers:::::
        Set critRemID = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
        Set listRemID = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1)
        Set critRemIDstart = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
        Set listRemIDstart = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2)

        Dim i, j As Integer
        i = 0
        j = 0

        Do
        If critRemID.Offset(i, 0) = listRemID.Offset(j, 0) Then
                critRemIDstart.Offset(i) = listRemIDstart.Offset(j)
                i = i + 1
                j = 0
        Else
                j = j + 1
        End If

        Loop While critRemID.Offset(i, 0) <> ""
    End Sub
```